# PHP: how convert this time string?

Tags: php, strftime

i would convert this time (strftime?)

```
2013-07-12T07:59:27+0000
```

in a more simple  to read "12/07/2013" (dd-mm-aaaa) and with +2 (i'm in Italy, so this time must be 09:59, no importance for seconds).

Thank you very much!

PS Could you tell me what "kinda of time expression" is, so next time i'll be more capable to search in Google without ask? :)

Comment: Check this out http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: This is the ISO [8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) international standard format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo date('d/m/Y H:i', strtotime('2013-07-12T07:59:27+0000'));
```

For more, read this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: '2013-07-12T07:59:27+0000 + 2 hours' to fit OP's question.